# IllegalArgumentException on bakemono-3.0-job.jar run freebaseRDFPrefilter

Tags: hadoop, freebase

I have working hadoop 2.4 on windows10 64 pro.
When I try to convert freebase raw gz file into standard rdf file by using this command,I got exceptions:

```
E:\infovore-3.0\bakemono\target>hadoop jar bakemono-3.0-job.jar run freebaseRDFPrefilter /user/Hanaky/InputDir/1.gz /user/Hanaky/InputDir/2.rdf
15/09/02 22:10:23 INFO support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@1706f7ec: startup date [Wed Sep 02 22:10:23 CST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
15/09/02 22:10:23 INFO xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [com/ontology2/bakemono/applicationContext.xml]
15/09/02 22:10:28 INFO annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor: JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
15/09/02 22:10:28 INFO mapreduce.SingleJobTool: Initializing SingleJobTool
15/09/02 22:10:38 ERROR bakemono.Main: Uncaught exception in application
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not create a Path from an empty string
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.checkPathArg(Path.java:127)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:135)
        at com.ontology2.bakemono.mapreduce.SelfAwareTool$1.apply(SelfAwareTool.java:36)
        at com.ontology2.bakemono.mapreduce.SelfAwareTool$1.apply(SelfAwareTool.java:33)
        at com.ontology2.bakemono.mapreduce.SelfAwareTool.getOutputPath(SelfAwareTool.java:204)
        at com.ontology2.bakemono.mapreduce.SingleJobTool.createJob(SingleJobTool.java:153)
        at com.ontology2.bakemono.mapreduce.SingleJobTool.run(SingleJobTool.java:90)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
        at com.ontology2.bakemono.MainBase$RunATool.run(MainBase.java:113)
        at com.ontology2.bakemono.MainBase.run(MainBase.java:51)
        at com.ontology2.bakemono.Main.main(Main.java:18)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
```

It seems simply didn't get the right path argument(s),but as I am a beginner,I can't deal with it.Could you help me figure it out please?